# WPGraphQL - How to fetch data based on a Where attribute?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, graphql, wp-graphql

I have created a post type called `LearnArticles` in wordpress and another post type `Learn Categories`. Now I have linked both of them and I can access the `Learn Categories` data under the `Learn Articles`. But when I am trying to fetch data of a particular category I am unable to find the Learn Categories field in the `Where` attribute of the `Learn Articles`.

[image]

But on the default post category, there is an option to filter using the category ID.

[image]

How can I get my custom category type `(Learn Category)` in the `Where` attribute?